# 書籍「サイバーセキュリティプログラミング」について

Tags: python

「サイバーセキュリティプログラミング - pythonで学ぶハッカー思考」の本を読み進めてるんですが、「NetCatの置き換え」で詰んでしまいました。P.24の「試してみる」とはどのようにして行えばいいのでしょうか？また、Pycharmを利用しているため、KaliLinuxは使っていません。それでもできることなのでしょうか？

追記
使ってる環境としてはPycharmというソフトでpythonのコードを実行しています。

NetCat の仕組みも理解していないのでなんとも言えませんが、NetCatはどのような処理を行うソフトなのでしょうか？ターミナルで、./bhnet.py -1 -p 9999 -cという動作を行った後、別のターミナルで、/ bhnet.py -t localhost  -p 9999 実行するわけですが、上手く実行されなくて困っています。スマホで投稿してるので、コードは今載せることできませんがこれで情報としてはよろしかったでしょうか？

Comment: その書籍を誰もが持っているとは限らないので、書籍を持っていない人でも「何に困っているのか」が分かるよう、もう少し詳しい情報を追記できませんか？検索してみると「netcatコマンドをPythonで実装してみよう」といった課題みたいですが、KaliLinuxを使っていないならどんな実行環境なのかといった情報も必要です。

Comment: [『サイバーセキュリティプログラミング』のサポートページ](https://github.com/oreilly-japan/black-hat-python-jp-support)

Comment: OS は Windows / macOS / Ubuntu などなどのうち、どれでしょうか？

Comment: 「上手く実行されなくて困っています」というのは、どのようなことを示しているのでしょうか。「期待するものと異なる出力であった」、「なんらかのエラーが発生した」などを、実際に得られた出力と合わせて追記すると回答が得られやすくなるかもしれません。

Answer (score 3):

上手く実行されないのは、以下で`-l`とすべきところを`-1`としたためだと思われます。`listen`の略の`l`です。

```
./bhnet.py -l -p 9999 -c
```

使用する環境は、Pythonで`socket`が動作すれば問題はないので、linux, Mac, Windows どれを使っても問題ないと思います。NetCatのWindows版もあるようです。ただし、Windowsは環境の違いがあるので、本に合わせて`linux`を使った方が学習しやすいと思います。`KaliLinux`は、Debian系なので、`KaliLinux`でなくても`Debian`や`Ubuntu`を使えば本と同じ操作でできると思います。他の`linux`でも、パッケージ管理が違いますが少し慣れれば問題ないと思います。

NetCatは、TCPパケットとUDPパケットの読み書きができるソフトで、簡易サーバーや簡易クライアントを簡単に作れる便利なものです。